# UISearchBar Resize issue

Tags: uisearchbar

I am having an issue where the UISearchBar keeps resizing once i click away then goes back, to the appropriate size.  I am setting the frame and the bounds like so in the init.

```
    [_searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];
    [_searchBar setBounds:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];
```

I am also doing this for layoutSubviews

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [_searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];
    [_searchBar setBounds:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];
}
```

[image: Search bar keeps resizing iOS7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the real true way to solve this is to use Autolayout with visualConstraints. The searchbox no longer resized once I started to use it.